# SQL Server : update join statement of two tables with multiple columns from existing table to match

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I need to update an existing table (`First`) with a new column (`Ticket_No_Calc`). Basically, there are two columns (`Doc_Header` and `Doc_No`) that I have to lookup/refer to in the first table against the second table (`Doc_No`) column.

The desired column `Ticket_No_Calc` result is retrieved from the column `Ticket_No`.

Below is the screenshot of sample data of the first table

[image: First Table]

and this is the screenshot of sample data of the second table

[image: Second Table]

Currently, in Excel, I use the following formula to get the desired column in the existing table

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FIRST!B2,'SECOND'!A:B,1,0),(VLOOKUP(FIRST!C2,'SECOND'!A:B,1,0)))
```

I am not sure how to do this in SQL. I know that I can get this done in SQL with the following formula if I only have to refer to one column `Doc_Header`:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No 
FROM First AS A 
LEFT JOIN Second AS B ON A.Doc_Header = B.Doc_NO ;
```

But I need to refer to two columns in the existing table. I have been researching for sometimes to get the correct command but I can't seem to be able to crack it.

Comment: "But I need to refer to two columns in the existing table"  what is your second field of your reference

Comment: Hi, Basically, there are two columns (Doc_Header and Doc_No) that I have to lookup/refer to in the (First) Table against the (Second) table (Doc_No) column

Comment: how 2 column refer with one column, BTW your values of Doc_No from first table is not matching with Doc_No of second table

Comment: Hi, this is just sample data, the  complete data will contain the said matches.Let me try to explain this. First condition is, if value in Doc_Header (First table) matches with Doc_No (Second table) then Ticket_No (from second table). When values from the doc_header (first table) do not match with the value from Doc_No (second table) then use the second condition which is values from Doc_No(first table) matches with Doc_No (Second table) then Ticket_No (from second table).

Comment: It is easier for others to understand your requirement if you can show meaningful sample data. Don't forget to include the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following statement may help

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No 
FROM First AS A 
INNER JOIN Second AS B ON (A.Doc_Header = B.Doc_NO) OR (A.Doc_NO = B.Doc_NO) ;
```

Comment: @SherendeepKaur kindly you can try to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the sample data provided this is query seems incorrect. But as per the comments mentioned in your question it is better to perform this in 2 steps.

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No 
FROM First AS A 
LEFT JOIN Second AS B ON A.Doc_Header = B.Doc_NO ;


UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No 
FROM First AS A 
LEFT JOIN Second AS B ON A.DOC_NO=B.DOC_NO
WHERE A.Doc_Header <> B.Doc_NO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Ticket_No_Calc = B.Ticket_No 
FROM First AS A ,Second AS B where A.Doc_Header = B.Doc_NO or A.Doc_NO = B.Doc_NO
```